# Displaying received data on the same web page after receiving it from AJAX call

Tags: php, ajax

I have 2 PHP files.

This is the JS Script code in my first PHP file, which is inside an EOD tag. It has two dynamic drop down lists and when an item in the second list is selected it submits an AJAX call to a second PHP file in order to pass it some data (variable chosenStudent) - this appears to work fine as I get the success message:

```
$js_array_leadersGroupsName = array("group1", "group2");
$js_array_students_lists = array(["Bob", "Jane"], ["Sally", "Tom"]);


$js_array_leadersGroupsName = json_encode($js_array_leadersGroupsName);
$js_array_students_lists = json_encode($js_array_students_lists);

    $Content3 = <<<EOD




       <form action="" id="myGroupSelectForm" method="post">
          <select id="selectGroup">
            <option>Choose a Group</option>
          </select>
            <select id="selectStudent">
            <option>Choose a Student</option>
          </select>
        </form>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">

        var select = document.getElementById("selectGroup"); 
        var options = {$js_array_leadersGroupsName}; 
        var i;

        for(i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
            var opt = options[i];
            var el = document.createElement("option");
            el.textContent = opt;
            el.value = opt;
            select.appendChild(el);
        }

        var studentList = {$js_array_students_lists}; 
        var select2 = document.getElementById("selectStudent");

        var a = document.getElementById('selectGroup');
        a.addEventListener('change', function() {

            var i;
            for(i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                    if ((this.value) == options[i]) {
                        var chosenStudentList = studentList[i];
                    }
                }

            var select = document.getElementById("selectStudent");
            var length = select.options.length;
            for (i = length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
              select.options[i] = null;
            }

            var i;
            for(i = 0; i < chosenStudentList.length; i++) {
                var opt = chosenStudentList[i][0];
                var el = document.createElement("option");
                el.textContent = opt;
                el.value = opt;
                select2.appendChild(el);
            }

            }, false);

            var b = document.getElementById('selectStudent');
            b.addEventListener('change', function() {
                var chosenSudent = this.value;
                alert(this.value);

                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/path/to/NewFile.php',
                data: "userID=" + chosenSudent,
                success: function(data)
                {
                    alert("success!");
                }
                });

                }, false);





         </script>

EOD;





 $Content3 .="\n";       
            return $Content3;
```

This is the code in my second PHP File which should receive the passed data and store it in $uid:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['userID']))
{
    $uid = $_POST['userID'];
    echo  $uid;
}
?>
```

My question:

I cannot get my second php file's echo command to display the $uid variable on the webpage after the second drop-down item is selected. How can this be done / what have I done wrong?

Comment: **Danger**: jQuery 2.x is unsupported and does not receive security updates. Upgrade to a current version of jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I got your point, because you want to parse javascript variable to php and use it in the same php file. In this case, I don't think it can be done, because when PHP file has been run, as I know, there is no way it's able to run one more time again.
So there are 2 ways you can consider to try:

1. Submit the form with post method to be able to use that variable, but the pros here is, it's kinda not friendly with client.

> ```
> ...
> // Get variable $chosenStudent if existed
> if (isset($_POST['chosenStudent'])) {
>     $uid = $_POST['chosenStudent'];
>     // Write your processing for new student here
> }
> ...
> <script>
>     b.addEventListener('change', function() {
>         document.getElementById("myGroupSelectForm").submit();
>     });
> </script>
> ```

2. Process everything in javascript. Here is the flow of code you may consider.

There are 2 different php file: File A and File B.

- You move all the complicated process into file B
- In file A, you just use javascript, send ajax to file B (get data or
  something, for rendering or calculating purpose)
- After all thing's done, just submit form into next process

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. Unfortunately, the change has now resulted in the success message failing. Do I need to make a change in the second PHP file to receive the data now in the JSON form?

Comment: Does it alert "success" or nothing happen when you try to send the post request ?

Comment: It did with my original code but not after changing the data and dataType lines

Comment: try the error function I added below the success function, can you tell me what is it printing out?

Comment: Hi, the error message displays the actual name of the chosen student (contents of the chosenStudent variable) that is meant to pass to the PHP file.

Comment: ah, it's getting that error because when **dataType: "json"** is set, the sent request data and the response has to be in json, so that's meant in your php file, you have to echo string in json format like this: **echo json_encode(["uid" => $uid]);**. You can refer my updated answer above

Comment: Thanks again, this results in success but back to my original issue where the received data will not echo to the web page. It says success but I cannot see the received data display on my web page under the drop down list. I really appreciate your time with this by the way!

Comment: about that, now you can just print out the **data** callback like: **let chosen_user = data.uid;**. Now you can use that data where ever you want. I also updated my answer above

Comment: The way he's parsing data is fine, you do not NEED a JSON object.

Comment: Im clearly missing something or not understanding. Where do I write the code to display the chosen student? I'm sorry if I am sounding dumb.

Comment: I have just found out that we don't need **dataType: "json"** in javascript, because when there is no option **dataType** is available, it will default use auto for response and request data (no matter what the data type is, response data type can be anything, but for request, it must be in json format. So there is no need to change your original php file, only javascript file is needed. I have updated my answer.

Comment: What line can I add (and on which file) to then print out the chosen user onto the webpage, under the dropdown list? I just cannot get the chosen user to display.

Comment: Sorry because I don't know what you are trying to do when you are posting the variable of dropdown list to php  file, do nothing on it and then you want to print it out. So that's why I just show you the way to print out the result of your php file in your ajax call. It would be helpful if you describe more details about your case, what you want to do, and then I may know what to do haha

Comment: Sorry ThienHuynh. I would like the passed value to be used in my new PHP file so that it can eventually identify the students ID and generate a chart using that students database data. I simply want to print out the chosen student name (from the new PHP file's code) on the webpage so that I can be confident that the new PHP file has the received data stored in a PHP variable.

Comment: ...and so I can be confident that I can write back to the same webpage from the new PHP file.

Comment: Ah so if I don't get you wrong, you are having a data of chosenStudent in your php file already, and now you just want to append those retrieved data to selectbox. Am I right ?

Comment: Better idea is, could you clarify me about this: after you got data from your php file successfully, where do you want to display outside in your current webpage above?

Comment: where do you want to display retrieved data in your current <form></form> up there ?

Comment: Not exactly. My first PHP has the java script drop downs. Once a student is selected it needs to be passed into a php variable. As this cannot happen in the same PHP file I need it to be passed to a new PHP file via ajax. In this new PHP file I want the received data to be stored in a php variable. I am trying to display the received data on the webpage via this new PHP file to check the new PHP file has the data in a php variable and to check I can write back to the webpage from this new PHP file.

Comment: I want to display it under the form or even outside the form

Comment: I've just updated my answer, did I get your point ?

Comment: Not quite as I need that data in a php variable. How can I get the passed data in a php variable?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215934/discussion-between-thienhuynh-and-sw123456).